# Cannot find module 'babylonjs'

Tags: babylonjs

**index.ts**

```
import { Engine } from '@babylonjs/core/Engine/engine';

[tsl] ERROR in ~/Documents/babylon1/src/index.ts(1,24)
  TS2307: Cannot find module '@babylonjs/core/Engines/engine'.
```

I've followed the steps on the Babylon documentation pages, and the troubleshooting notes at https://doc.babylonjs.com/features/npm_support#error-ts2307-cannot-find-module-babylonjs-or-other-modules. I've added "babylonjs" to tscong.json, but I'm still getting the "Cannot find module @babylonjs/core" error.

**package.json**

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babylonjs/core": "^4.0.3",
    "ts-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "typescript": "^3.7.4",
    "webpack": "^4.41.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.1"
},
"dependencies": {
  "babylonjs": "^4.0.3"
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "strictNullChecks": false,
        "module": "es6",
        "target": "es6",
        "types": [
            "babylonjs"
        ]
    }
}
```

I did `npm install` just to make sure nothing is missing.

Comment: I got it to compile by doing `npm install -D @types/babylonjs`, and changing the `import` to `babylonjs`. It's not ideal, because it imports the entire 2.5MB library, rather than individual modules, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

The following setup works. The `@babylonjs/core/...` imports resolve correctly, and `webpack-dev-server` builds and reloads automatically.

**package.json**

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@babylonjs/core": "^4.0.3",
  "ts-loader": "^6.2.1",
  "typescript": "^3.7.4",
  "webpack": "^4.41.5",
  "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
  "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.1"
},
"dependencies": {}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "module": "esNext",
    "target": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  }
}
```

NOTE: `types: ["babylonjs"]` doesn't seem to be necessary

**webpack.config.js**

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.tsx?$/,
      use: 'ts-loader',
      exclude: /node_modules/
    },
  ],
},
resolve: {
  extensions: [ '.tsx', '.ts', '.js' ],
},
output: {
  filename: 'bundle.js'
},
devServer: {
  contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
  compress: true,
  hot: true
}
```